# How long were the Apollo astronauts allowed to breathe 100% oxygen at 1 atmosphere continuously?

Tags: apollo-program, astronauts, safety, health, oxygen

[This answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/37461/12102) explains that from the time they suited up "in the Suit Lab before launch" until the time the capsule started depressurizing during ascent, the Apollo astronauts were breathing 100% oxygen at slightly above 1 bar (1 atmosphere).

100% Oxygen at 1 bar (100 kPa) partial pressure is toxic, or at least bad for you  if you breathe it long enough. Presumably you'll be okay if it's not too long, so there must have been some time limit.

**Question(s):**

- How long were the Apollo astronauts allowed to continuously breathe 100% oxygen at 1 bar?
- Where there ever situations where the time was exceeded, and they literally had to "take a breather" and breathe something with a substantially lower oxygen partial pressure?

Comment: [Very relevant question](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/13469/oxygen-toxicity-vs-apollo-mission-preparation) but not quite a duplicate

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are two different effects of oxygen toxicity, the Lorrain-Smith-effect and the Paul-Bert-effect. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxygen_toxicity).

The Lorrain-Smith-effect may occur at a partial oxygen pressure above 0.5 bar for more than about 24 hours. It is a lung toxicity.

The Paul-Bert-effect may occur at a partial pressure above 1.6 bar for minutes to a few hours. It is a central nervous system toxicity.

> The time to onset of symptoms is highly variable but most individuals
>   can tolerate 12-16 hours of oxygen at 1.0 ATA, 8-14 hours at 1.5 ATA,
>   and 3-6 hours at 2.0 ATA before developing mild symptoms.

10 hours at a partial oxygen pressure of 1 bar may cause a 2 % reduction of the vital capacity.

[Source](https://www.diverite.com/articles/oxygen-toxicity-signs-and-symptoms/)

For the Apollo astronauts the time when breathing pure oxygen at a pressure above 0.5 bar was limited to a few hours.

But to reduce the probability of decompression sickness extended prebreathing of pure oxygen over 3 to 4 hours is helpful. See [1](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19870017960.pdf), [2](https://www.faa.gov/pilots/safety/pilotsafetybrochures/media/DCS.pdf), [3](https://www.physiology.org/doi/pdf/10.1152/japplphysiol.91099.2008).

Comment: What is "ATA"? That's a new one to me.

Comment: @OrganicMarble ATA or ata is the absolut pressure in kp/cm^2, outdated for over forty years. Just replace it by bar, the error is small and negligible.

Comment: Thanks! I learned something.  By the way, the suit pressure control was stated in "inches of water", that's one I hadn't heard in a long time.

Comment: Interesting!  U-2 and SR-71 pilots both breathed 100% oxygen during their flights.  I guess they also didn't exceed the 12-16 hour mark.

Comment: @ErinAnne The U-2 and SR-71 pilots breathed 100% oxygen at a pressure substantially lower than 1 bar or 1 ATA, so they could exceed 12 to 16 hours without problems just like the astronauts during flight.

Comment: @OrganicMarble the last time I heard of inches of water was in reference to pipe organ maintenance (don't ask) and those predate space suits by a bit.

Comment: @uhoh the wind tunnels I used in college used mercury manometers so we did use "inches of mercury" then...probably all digital now.

Comment: @OrganicMarble ata is atmospheres ("atm") except clarified to be absolute (like psia) rather than relative to ambient. So 1.013 bar.

Comment: @hobbs Thanks! Uwe explained it to me in the 2nd comment a while back.

Answer (score 6):

The Crew Systems Division post-flight [report](https://www.hq.nasa.gov/alsj/a11/A11CSD.pdf) for Apollo 11 states that:

> Suiting was completed at 06:17 with an O<sub>2</sub> concentration check at 
>   06:21 indicating 100% O<sub>2</sub> in the  suit.
>
> Launch was at 08:32 and the crew removed their helmets at ~08:45.

Comment: I thought that for one of the Apollo missions the launch was delayed and they remained suited, sitting in the capsule, for more than just a few hours, maybe I'm misremembering.

Comment: Could well be. I'll look for other CSD postflight reports. Or maybe there's a flight rule.

Comment: Lots of Apollo "Flight Mission Rule Documents" (FMRD) out there but can't find a "Launch Mission Rule Document" (LMRD).  Will ask a question.

Comment: @uhoh There was a launch delay of nearly three hours during the Mecury-Redstone 3 mission with Alan Shepard.

Comment: @uhoh Apollo launch delays were limited by the launch windows, the longest window for Apollo 8 at 4 hours and 41 minutes. Most launch windows were shorter than 4 hours.

Comment: Launch delay for Apollo 17 was 2 hours and 40 minutes, so the time with 100 % O2 at 1 bar was substantially longer.

Comment: It would be good to get what the actual rule was. Haven't found it yet though.

Comment: The Shuttle flight rules weren't much help, but there is one about prebreathing for EVA that was interesting: A MINIMUM OF 4 HOURS UNBROKEN PREBREATHE WITH > 95 PERCENT
O2 IS REQUIRED AT A CABIN PRESSURE ABOVE 12.5 PSI PRIOR TO
ANY CABIN OR AIRLOCK DEPRESSURIZATION BELOW 8 PSI.  So they were allowed (required) to breathe pure O2 for > 4 hours above 12.5 psi. (This is off-nominal, the normal prebreathe was at 10.2 psi)